# Updating another ViewModel when button clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to update another ViewModel when a button is clicked. That Viewmodel already has a button that updates its own ViewModel but I want the exact same functionallity on another viewModel

Here is my code:

OlyckorViewModel (The view that I want to update and that already has a button that updates it) **`SearchActiveInvestigationsCommand` is the button binding that updates it**

```
public class OlyckorViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        private readonly ISosServiceDelegate _sosService;
        private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
        private string _searchConditionDiarienummer;
        private string _searchConditionFartygsnamn;
        private string _searchConditionRegisterbeteckning;
        private int? _searchConditionIMONummer;
        private DateTime? _searchConditionHaendelseDatum;
        private string _searchConditionOlyckshaendelsetypKod;
        private bool _isSearching;
        private bool _isSearchExpanded = true;
        private ObservableCollection<SosListOlycka> _olyckor;
        private SosListOlycka _selectedOlycka;
        private string _statusText;

        public OlyckorViewModel(ISosServiceDelegate sosService, ILoggerFacade logger, IDialogService dialogServce)
        {
            logger.Log("Initializing OlyckorViewModel", Category.Debug, Priority.Low);

            _sosService = sosService;
            _dialogService = dialogServce;

            SearchCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSearch, CanExecuteSearch);
            SearchActiveInvestigationsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSearchActiveInvestigations, CanExecuteSearchActiveInvestigations);
            OpenCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteOpen, CanExecuteOpen);
            DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteDelete, CanExecuteDelete);
            CreatePdfReportCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCreatePdfReport, CanExecuteCreatePdfReport);
        }


 private void ExecuteSearch()
        {
            if (IsSearching)
                return;

            IsSearching = true;
            StatusText = "Söker olyckor...";

            var criteria = new SosOlyckaSearchCriteria();
            criteria.Diarienummer = SearchConditionDiarienummer;
            criteria.Fartygsnamn = SearchConditionFartygsnamn;
            criteria.Registerbeteckning = SearchConditionRegisterbeteckning;
            criteria.IMONummer = SearchConditionIMONummer;
            criteria.HaendelseDatum = SearchConditionHaendelseDatum;
            criteria.OlyckshaendelseTypKod = SearchConditionOlyckshaendelsetypKod;

            _sosService.SearchOlyckor(
                criteria,
                olyckor =>
                {
                    HandleResultFromSearch(olyckor);
                },
                exception =>
                {
                    IsSearching = false;
                    StatusText = "Misslyckades att söka olyckor";
                    DialogHelper.ShowException(exception);
                }
            );
        }

private void HandleResultFromSearch(SosSearchResult<SosListOlycka> olyckor)
        {
            IsSearching = false;
            IsSearchExpanded = false;
            Olyckor = new ObservableCollection<SosListOlycka>(olyckor.Items);

            StatusText = Olyckor.Count + " " + (Olyckor.Count == 1 ? "olycka." : "olyckor.");

            if (olyckor.IsResultTruncated)
            {
                var statusTextResultTruncated = "Resultatet var för stort (" + olyckor.OriginalNumberOfHits + " olyckor) och trunkerades på servern.";
                StatusText += " " + statusTextResultTruncated;
            }

            // if search result only contains a single item, it should be opened
            if (Olyckor.Count == 1)
                DialogHelper.OpenOlyckaDialog(Olyckor[0].OlyckaId);
        }
```

OlyckaViewModel (The viewModel that is supposed to have a save button to update the viewmodel above) **`SaveCommand` is the button binding that I want to update like the button above**

```
 public class OlyckaViewModel : DialogWindowViewModel
        {
            private readonly ISosServiceDelegate _sosService;
            private readonly Repository _repository;
            private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
            private readonly IInteractionService _interactionService;
            private readonly FroCodesViewModel _froCodesViewModel;
            private SosOlycka _model;
            private SosOlycksorsak _selectedOlycksorsak;
            private SosOlycksorsak _selectedHuvudorsak;
            private SosStegIOlycksfoerlopp _selectedStegIOlycksfoerlopp;
            private SosStegIOlycksfoerlopp _selectedInledandeSteg;
            private SosOlycka _selectedOtherOlycka;
            private OlyckorViewModel _olyckorlist;

            private readonly ObservableCollection<CheckBoxListItemViewModel<TrsFartygsunderkategori>> _fartygsunderkategorier = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxListItemViewModel<TrsFartygsunderkategori>>();
            private int? _olycksrapportIdToHaemtmarkeraWhenSaving;
            private ObservableCollection<SosListOlycka> _olyckor;
            private SosListOlycka _selectedOlycka;
            private bool _isSearching;
            private bool _isSearchExpanded = true;


            private readonly List<KnownValue> _oestEllerVaest = new List<KnownValue>()
        {
            new KnownValue("Välj", null),
            new KnownValue("E", "E"),
            new KnownValue("W", "W")
        };

            private readonly List<KnownValue> _nordEllerSyd = new List<KnownValue>()
        {
            new KnownValue("Välj", null),
            new KnownValue("N", "N"),
            new KnownValue("S", "S")
        };

            public OlyckaViewModel(ISosServiceDelegate sosService, Repository repository, IDialogService dialogService, IInteractionService interactionService)
            {
                _sosService = sosService;
                _repository = repository;
                _dialogService = dialogService;
                _interactionService = interactionService;
                _froCodesViewModel = new FroCodesViewModel(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISitsServiceDelegate>());



                SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSave);
                ReloadCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteReload, CanExecuteIfExistingOlycka);
                CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(Close);
                DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteDelete, CanExecuteIfExistingOlycka);
                AvslutaUtredningCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteAvslutaUtredning, CanExecuteIfExistingOlycka);
                CreatePdfReportCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCreatePdfReport, CanExecuteIfExistingOlycka);
                AddOlycksorsakCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteAddOlycksorsak);
                RemoveOlycksorsakCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRemoveOlycksorsak, CanExecuteRemoveOlycksorsak);
                AddStegIOlycksfoerloppCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteAddStegIOlycksfoerlopp);
                RemoveStegIOlycksfoerloppCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRemoveStegIOlycksfoerlopp, CanExecuteRemoveStegIOlycksfoerlopp);
                FetchFartygsinformationFromSitsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteFetchFartygsinformationFromSits);
                NewOlyckaFromHaendelseCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteNewOlyckaFromHaendelse);
                OpenOtherOlyckaCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteOpenOtherOlycka, CanExecuteOpenOtherOlycka);
                MoveOlyckaToNewHaendelseCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteMoveOlyckaToNewHaendelse);
                MoveOlyckaToOtherHaendelseCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteMoveOlyckaToOtherHaendelse);
                MarkSelectedOlycksorsakAsHuvudorsakCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteMarkSelectedOlycksorsakAsHuvudorsak);
                MarkSelectedStegIOlycksfoerloppAsInledandeStegCommand = new DelegateCommand(MarkSelectedStegIOlycksfoerloppAsInledandeSteg);
                SearchActiveInvestigationsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSearchActiveInvestigations, CanExecuteSearchActiveInvestigations);
            }



            public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand ReloadCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand CloseCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand AvslutaUtredningCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand CreatePdfReportCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand AddOlycksorsakCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand RemoveOlycksorsakCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand AddStegIOlycksfoerloppCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand RemoveStegIOlycksfoerloppCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand FetchFartygsinformationFromSitsCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand NewOlyckaFromHaendelseCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand OpenOtherOlyckaCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand MoveOlyckaToNewHaendelseCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand MoveOlyckaToOtherHaendelseCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand MarkSelectedOlycksorsakAsHuvudorsakCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand MarkSelectedStegIOlycksfoerloppAsInledandeStegCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand SearchActiveInvestigationsCommand { get; private set; }
            public DelegateCommand SearchCommand { get; private set; }

            public FroCodesViewModel FroCodesViewModel { get { return _froCodesViewModel; } }

            public OlyckorViewModel OlyckorViewModel { get { return _olyckorlist; } }
            public SosOlycka Model
            {
                get { return _model; }
                private set
                {
                    if (value != _model)
                    {
                        _model = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Model);
                        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsExistingOlycka);
                        RaiseCanExecuteChangedForOlyckaCommands();

                        LoadDescriptionsForFroCodes();

                        SynchronizeFromModel();
                    }
                }
            }



private void ExecuteSave()
            {
                if (IsBusy)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot save olycka, is already busy");

                SynchronizeToModel();

                // Validate ad-acta
                List<string> missingAdActaFields = null;
                if (Model.MyndighetensUtredningAvslutad.HasValue)
                {
                    missingAdActaFields = DataHelper.ValidateAdActa(Model);
                }

                // Validate skrovskada
                List<string> missingSkrovskadaFields = null;
                if (Model.SosFartygsskada.Skrovskada == "J")
                {
                    missingSkrovskadaFields = DataHelper.ValidateSkrovskada(Model);
                }

                if ((missingAdActaFields != null && missingAdActaFields.Count > 0)
                    || (missingSkrovskadaFields != null && missingSkrovskadaFields.Count > 0))
                {
                    // Bring up window of missing fields (or update if already open)
                    var vm = _dialogService.GetOpenDialogs().OfType<MissingFieldsViewModel>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (vm != null)
                    {
                        vm.AdActaFields = missingAdActaFields;
                        vm.SkrovskadaFields = missingSkrovskadaFields;
                        _dialogService.Activate(vm);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MissingFieldsViewModel>();
                        vm.AdActaFields = missingAdActaFields;
                        vm.SkrovskadaFields = missingSkrovskadaFields;
                        _dialogService.Show(vm);
                    }



                    //




                    // Cancel save operation
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Close window with missing fields if open)
                    var vm = _dialogService.GetOpenDialogs().OfType<MissingFieldsViewModel>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (vm != null)
                    {
                        vm.Close();
                    }
                }

                SetBusy("Sparar ändringar...");

                _sosService.SaveOlycka(
                    Model,
                    result =>
                    {
                        // load olycka using the id returned from save method (useful if olycka was new / not previously persisted)
                        ResetBusy();

                        if (IsGoingToHaemtmarkeraWhenSaving)
                        {
                            SetBusy("Markerar olycksrapport som hämtad...");

                            var rosService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRosServiceDelegate>();
                            rosService.HaemtmarkeraOlycksrapport(
                                OlycksrapportIdToHaemtmarkeraWhenSaving.Value,
                                result,
                                () =>
                                {
                                    ResetBusy();
                                    OlycksrapportIdToHaemtmarkeraWhenSaving = null;
                                    LoadOlycka(result);
                                },
                                haemtmarkeraException =>
                                {
                                    ResetBusy();
                                    DialogHelper.ShowException(haemtmarkeraException);
                                }
                            );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LoadOlycka(result);
                        }
                    },
                    exception =>
                    {
                        ResetBusy();
                        DialogHelper.ShowException(exception);
                    }
                );

                ExecuteSearchActiveInvestigations();
            }
```

I know it's alot of code, I just wanted to make sure not to miss anything.

I tried to copy the same code from the already working button to the button I want to work the same but it didn't work and I suspect it's because I didn't tell it to update another view and not itself. I could be wrong tho.

I appreciate any help,

Comment: It would help if you were to strip this code down to the essential parts that are directly relevant to the specific task you're asking about. But very generally, if you want object A to call a method on object B when C happens, give A an `event` or an `Action` property that is raised/called when C happens. Then some higher-authority viewmodel can wire up the necessary behavior without introducing vexatious dependencies. Or you could just suck up the dependency issues and give A a reference to B and hard-code it, if the above method is hard to get your head around.

Answer (score 1):

Raise an event from OlyckaViewModel with the required parameters and subscribe in OlyckorViewModel. 
Make the code common in the SearchActiveInvestigationsCommand and call the same function from the subscribed event method.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to update another ViewModel when a button is clicked.

In the *another* viewmodel centralize the update code into a public method.

1. In the App code, make a static reference to the VM in question.
2. Make the *another* viewmodel place a reference to itself onto the app as a static reference.
3. Centralize the update code into a public method on that VM. The method may have multiple variables which have to be pass through to do any update from any foreign VMs or button clicks from views.
4. On the button click, get the global `app` from (see [Application.Current Property (System.Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Application.Current);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)) and find the reference to the VM in question. Then call the update method.

Comment: Can you give an example? I've never done it before. Thank you

Comment: @Simon.S One uses the `Application.Current` property to get the current app. Other than that *you* have to put in the method calls and call them. Don't make it harder than that, it is actually easy.